# Tensorflow: predicting a point from an image, training model with a point labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, multivalue

I want to create a model which can predict a point from an image.
I have a dataset with training images. Those images are splitted between 24 dirs.
I have prepared an json file containing a (x, y) values for every image.

example:

```
"dir22": {
        "frame_00001_rgb": {
            "x": 363.693829827852,
            "y": 278.2191728859505
        },
        "frame_00002_rgb": {
            "x": 330.9709780765119,
            "y": 283.34142472069004
        },
...
...
"dir23": {
        "frame_00001_rgb": {
            "x": 212.5232358000000,
            "y": 156.3342191728855
        },
        "frame_00002_rgb": {
            "x": 230.69497097807351,
            "y": 253.75341424720690
        },
```

My model looks like this:

```py
img_width, img_height = 640, 480

train_data_dir = 'v_data/train'

epochs = 10
batch_size = 16

input_tensor = tf.keras.Input(shape=(img_width,img_height,3))
base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(weights='imagenet',include_top=False ,input_tensor=input_tensor)

top_model = tf.keras.Sequential()
top_model.add(tf.keras.Flatten(input_shape=base_model.output_shape[1:]))
top_model.add(tf.keras.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
top_model.add(tf.keras.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
top_model.add(tf.keras.Dense(2))

model = tf.keras.Model(input= base_model.input, output= top_model(base_model.output))

for layer in model.layers[-15:]:
    layer.trainable = False


optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)

model.compile(loss='mse',
            optimizer=optimizer,
            metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
```

now I have loaded images from my dir:

```py
train_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size)
```

```
Found 15678 images belonging to 24 classes.
```

now how can I assign a label for each image and train my model with it?

Comment: Default activation is relu for Dense, I think you should scale your outputs between 0 and 1 and use sigmoid instead and then rescale them

Comment: This probably needs to be tackled as a regression problem. Not a classification problem. I hope that's what you have in mind. That aside, seems you already have x, y coordinates prepared. So what exactly is the question? Is it how to provide the labels in the JSON file  along side the data of `train_datagen`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for. Also I have made last three layers as described here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression. Should I do something additional for this, as a regression problem?

Comment: @JakubBalicki no I think you're fine. I was just pointing that out because you used the word "label". But while reading, I realized you are talking about a regression problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, you need to write a custom data generator.

### Importing necessary libraries

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from skimage.io import imread # Used for image processing
from skimage.transform import resize # Used for image processing
import json
import numpy as np
```

### Defining our own data generator

I followed [this](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) link to get an idea of how to do this. And customized it to your problem.

We need to fill in the following functions.

```
class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'



    def __init__(self, directory, target_json, batch_size=32, target_size=(128, 128), shuffle=True):
        ...

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        ...

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        ...

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        ...

    def __data_generation(self, list_paths, list_paths_wo_ext):
        'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
        ...
```

#### Let's look at what variables we define

```
self.target_size = # Final size of the images
self.batch_size = # Batch size
self.target_json = # Path to the json file
self.directory = # Where the training data is

self.img_paths = # Contains image paths with extension
self.img_paths_wo_ext = # Contains the image paths without extension

self.targets = # The dataframe containing targets loaded from the json
self.shuffle = # Shuffle data at start of each epoch?
```

### The JSON file

Your JSON file needs to be **exactly** in this format. This is probably what you have exactly too. But make sure it's 100% this format.

```
{'dir20': {'frame_00001_rgb': {'x': 363.693829827852, 'y': 278.2191728859505}, 'frame_00002_rgb': {'x': 330.9709780765119, 'y': 283.34142472069004}}, 'dir21': {'frame_00001_rgb': {'x': 363.693829827852, 'y': 278.2191728859505}, 'frame_00002_rgb': {'x': 330.9709780765119, 'y': 283.34142472069004}}, 'dir22': {'frame_00001_rgb': {'x': 363.693829827852, 'y': 278.2191728859505}, 'frame_00002_rgb': {'x': 330.9709780765119, 'y': 283.34142472069004}}, 'dir23': {'frame_00001_rgb': {'x': 363.693829827852, 'y': 278.2191728859505}, 'frame_00002_rgb': {'x': 330.9709780765119, 'y': 283.34142472069004}}, 'dir24': {'frame_00001_rgb': {'x': 212.5232358, 'y': 156.3342191728855}, 'frame_00002_rgb': {'x': 230.6949709780735, 'y': 253.7534142472069}}}
```

Next we need to convert this to a  pandas dataframe. For that we define the following function. It's a bit complex due to the nature of your file. But here's what's happening.

- Load the json and create a dataframe which contain columns like `dir20.frame_00002_rgb.x`.
- Create a multi index by splitting the column to 3 levels (e.g. dir20, frame_00002, x)
- Use `stack` to bring both `dir*` and `frame_*` as indices
- Reformat the index so that it contains the full path for each image and each record has two columns (`x` and `y`).

```
def json_to_df(json_path, directory):
          with open(json_path,'r') as f:
            s = json.load(f)
          df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(s)
          ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([col.split('.') for col in df.columns])
          df.columns = ind
          df = df.stack(level=[0,1])
          df = df.set_index(df.index.droplevel(0))
          df = df.set_index(pd.Index([os.path.sep.join([directory]+list(c)) for c in df.index.values]))
          return df
```

### Rest of the code

I won't go in to great details of what's going on in the other parts as it is quite straight forward. But we're essentially getting a single batch of data by reading the images, resizing and getting the correct `x`, `y` values from the dataframe we generated.

### Full code

Here's the full code for the data generator.

```
class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'



    def __init__(self, directory, target_json, batch_size=32, target_size=(128, 128), shuffle=True):
        'Initialization'
        self.target_size = target_size
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.target_json = target_json
        self.directory = directory

        self.img_paths = [] 
        self.img_paths_wo_ext = []      
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
            for file in files:
                if file.lower().endswith(".jpg") or file.lower().endswith(".png"):
                    self.img_paths.append(os.path.join(root, file))
                    self.img_paths_wo_ext.append(os.path.splitext(os.path.join(root, file))[0])

        def json_to_df(json_path, directory):
          with open(json_path,'r') as f:
            s = json.load(f)
          df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(s)
          ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([col.split('.') for col in df.columns])
          df.columns = ind
          df = df.stack(level=[0,1])
          df = df.set_index(df.index.droplevel(0))
          df = df.set_index(pd.Index([os.path.sep.join([directory]+list(c)) for c in df.index.values]))
          return df

        self.targets = json_to_df(self.target_json, self.directory)
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()



    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return int(np.floor(len(self.img_paths) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        # Generate indexes of the batch
        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

        # Find list of IDs
        list_paths = [self.img_paths[k] for k in indexes]
        list_paths_wo_ext = [self.img_paths_wo_ext[k] for k in indexes]
        # Generate data
        X, y = self.__data_generation(list_paths, list_paths_wo_ext)

        return X, y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.img_paths))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __data_generation(self, list_paths, list_paths_wo_ext):
        'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
        # Initialization
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.target_size, 3))
        y = self.targets.loc[list_paths_wo_ext].values

        # Generate data
        for i, ID in enumerate(list_paths):
            # Store sample

            X[i,] = resize(imread(ID),self.target_size)


        return X, y
```

### Using the datagenerator

Here's how you'd use the data generator.

```
train_datagen = iter(DataGenerator(train_data_dir, './train/data.json', batch_size=2))


x, y = next(train_datagen)
print(x)
print(y)
```

which gives,

```
[[0.01377145 0.01377145 0.01377145]
   [0.00242393 0.00242393 0.00242393]
   [0.         0.         0.        ]
   ...
   [0.0037837  0.0037837  0.0037837 ]
   [0.0037837  0.0037837  0.0037837 ]
   [0.0037837  0.0037837  0.0037837 ]]

  ...

  [[0.37398897 0.3372549  0.17647059]
   [0.38967525 0.35294118 0.19215686]
   [0.42889093 0.39215686 0.23137255]
   ...
   [0.72156863 0.62889093 0.33085172]
   [0.71372549 0.61176471 0.31764706]
   [0.70588235 0.59359681 0.30340074]]]]

[[363.69382983 278.21917289]
 [330.97097808 283.34142472]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive explaination. That was exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate the time and effort you put to answer my question :)

Comment: @JakubBalicki, Glad I could help :)